# ion-select not showing selected option with FormBuilder (Ionic 3)

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic2, ionic3

Take the following html

```
  <form [formGroup]="detailsForm">

  <ion-list>
  <ion-item>
    <ion-label>Gaming</ion-label>
    <ion-select formControlName="gaming">
      <ion-option value="nes">NES</ion-option>
      <ion-option value="n64">Nintendo64</ion-option>
      <ion-option value="ps">PlayStation</ion-option>
      <ion-option value="genesis">Sega Genesis</ion-option>
      <ion-option value="saturn">Sega Saturn</ion-option>
      <ion-option value="snes">SNES</ion-option>
    </ion-select>
  </ion-item>
  </ion-list>

  </form>
```

And in your component

```
this.detailsForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      gaming:['nes',Validators.required]
    });
```

I would expect to see 'NES' as the selected option when the view is loaded. However, it does not appear. If you instead use [(ngModel)] it will work.

Am I doing something wrong, or has the most recent ionic update caused this issue?

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just an issue with 3.1. It's either a breaking change with passing the whole event vs. the value as it used to, or has something to do with firing `ionChange` when the component loads before user interaction (or the first thing is causing the second). Use 3.0 for now.

Answer (score 2):

Here is how I solved this issue (as it is still happening in Ionic 3.5.0):

```
<ion-select class="form-select" 
            [selectOptions]="stateOptions"
            [(ngModel)]="state" 
            [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"
            (ionChange)="stateChanged(state)" (click)="onSelectClicked()">
  <ion-option *ngFor="let state of states">{{state}}</ion-option>
</ion-select>
```

And the corresponding TypeScript:

```
public onSelectClicked (): void {
  const options: HTMLCollectionOf<Element> = document.getElementsByClassName('alert-tappable alert-radio')
  setTimeout(() => {
    let i: number = 0
    const len: number = options.length
    for (i; i < len; i++) {
      if ((options[i] as HTMLElement).attributes[3].nodeValue === 'true') { // This is the selected option
        options[i].scrollIntoView({block: 'end', behavior: 'smooth'})
      }
    }
  }, 500) // Leave enough time for the popup to render
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if there is a way to do it with forms but I have been using
a `ng-model` and it is working great.

Look at the code below:

```
<ion-list>
    <ion-item>
        <ion-label>Gaming</ion-label>
        <ion-select [(ngModel)]=gaming>
            <ion-option value="nes">NES</ion-option>
            <ion-option value="n64">Nintendo64</ion-option>
            <ion-option value="ps">PlayStation</ion-option>
            <ion-option value="genesis">Sega Genesis</ion-option>
            <ion-option value="saturn">Sega Saturn</ion-option>
            <ion-option value="snes">SNES</ion-option>
        </ion-select>
    </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

and in the .ts file declare gaming to be a global variable by calling 
this before the constructor

```
public gaming: any;
```

and then insert the value

```
$scope.gaming=['nes'];
```

this should work fine.