# Ionic 4 - ion-select does not scroll to selected item in alert

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, scroll, ionic4, ion-select

I'm using `ionic 4.7.0`.

The problem I'm reporting happens on Chrome and Firefox.

Actual Behaviour:

Using `ion-select` with a big list of options, when you open the alert, `ion-select` does not automatically scroll to the selected value. The user sees the first value in the list of options and he might think that nothing is selected

Expected Behaviour:

When the alert is open, the view automatically center on the selected value

I created this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-4-template-9zf5yx?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhome%2Fhome.page.ts) to highlight the behaviour, we can see on the stackblitz that on loading the view, the selected value is `11:00` but when you open the alert (by clicking on ion-select), I would expect the view to be automatically scrolled on the selected value.

**Is that expected behaviour with ion-select?**

I found a few questions talking about the same subject but nothing that really answers the question:

- [Ion-select doesn't scroll in Ionic 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54589530/ion-select-doesnt-scroll-in-ionic-3):
  This one gives a solution with CSS that can't work with ionic 4 because ionic 4 uses web Components that are not modifiable
- [ion-select not showing selected option with FormBuilder (Ionic 3)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43681160/ion-select-not-showing-selected-option-with-formbuilder-ionic-3): Same as above
- https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-v3/issues/1005: Some scroll bug with ion-select that is suppose to be fixed with ionic 3.9.5, so I guess it's not the same problem

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is currently not a feature in Ionic but there is an [open issue](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/19296). Give it a thumbs up to increase its priority.

For the moment you can use a workaround:

```
window.addEventListener('ionAlertDidPresent', e => {
  const selected = (e.target as HTMLElement).querySelector('[aria-checked="true"]');
  selected && selected.scrollIntoView();
});
```

This listener will fire each time an alert is preseted. It then looks for the (first) selected element using the `aria-checked` HTML attribute and scrolls it into view.

You might want to take a look at [the parameters for `scrollIntoView()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView), e.g. to scroll so the selected item is at the bottom.

To only affect the `ion-select` alerts you can check if the alert has the `select-alert` (or `single-select-alert`) class. To only affect a single alert you can give the alert an ID by passing it in the `interfaceOptions` property of `ion-select`.

As mentioned, this is a workaround and might stop working if the component changes.

Comment: OMG, I should have found the github issue/feature request/bug. I did not want to believe that this was not working by default, I really thought I was doing something wrong.

Answer (score 2):

I recently rewrote our `autoscroll` directive, so I thought I'd share it here. It works for all IonSelect interfaces (Alert, Popover and ActionSheet).

```js
import { Directive, HostListener } from '@angular/core';
import { IonSelect } from '@ionic/angular';

/**
 * Autoscroll to the selected option of an ion-select when opened.
 */
@Directive({
  selector: 'ion-select[autoscroll]'
})
export class AutoscrollSelectDirective {

  constructor(
    private ionSelect: IonSelect
  ) {}

  @HostListener('click')
  scrollSoon(): void {
    let keBab = '';
    switch (this.ionSelect.interface) {
      case 'alert': keBab = 'Alert'; break;
      case 'action-sheet': keBab = 'ActionSheet'; break;
      case 'popover': keBab = 'Popover'; break;
    }

    if (keBab) {
      window.addEventListener(
        `ion${keBab}DidPresent`,
        e => {
          const parent: Element = <any>e.target;
          const scrollTarget = keBab === 'ActionSheet'
              ? parent.querySelector('.action-sheet-selected')
              : parent.querySelector('[aria-checked=true]')?.closest('.select-interface-option');
          if (scrollTarget) {
            scrollTarget.scrollIntoView();
          }
        },
        {once: true}
      );
    }
  }

}
```